# Approval of android BLUETOOTH permission in unity3d

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-permissions

I'll do Camera and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE Permission in unity3d Script.It was approved through RequestUserPermission.

```
Permission.RequestUserPermission(Permission.Camera);
Permission.RequestUserPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageWrite);
```

However, for BLUETOOTH and BLUETOOTH_ADMIN, the PopUp does not appear using the above method.

```
Permission.RequestUserPermission("android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN");
Permission.RequestUserPermission("android.permission.BLUETOOTH");
```

Can you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: it is because those permissions don't need approval

Comment: However, errors occur. 'current process has android.permission.BLUETOOTH'

Comment: that does not look like error

Comment: Error message : Need BLUETOOTH permission: Neither user 10239 nor current process has android.permission.BLUETOOTH.

Comment: did you declare that permission in manifest?

Comment: I wrote it but it didn't work. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>

Comment: are you sure you have put it into the right place in manifest?